# Android CheckBoxPreference java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: android

I have this CheckBoxPreference in my code. I have implemented onSharedPreferenceChanged() in my code to perform some action. The problem is that when i click on the checkbox preference, the function gets called in a loop with same value. Can anyone help me with this?

Here are the relevant code snippets:

onSharedPreferenceChanged() section in preference activity:

```
if(key.equals(LOCATION_UPDATE_KEY)) {
        boolean update = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(LOCATION_UPDATE_KEY, false);
        Log.v("preferences", update + "");
        editor.putBoolean(LOCATION_UPDATE_KEY, update);
        editor.commit();
}
```

preference activity's xml section:

```
<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="Location">
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:title="Track Location"
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:summary="Keep track of handset location (Consumes Battery)"
        android:key="track_option" />
    <ListPreference
        android:title="Location Update Source"
        android:summary=""
        android:key="track_source"
        android:defaultValue="2"
        android:entries="@array/location_sources"
        android:entryValues="@array/location_sources_values"
        android:dependency="track_option" />
    <ListPreference
        android:title="Location Update Interval"
        android:summary=""
        android:key="track_interval"
        android:defaultValue="2"
        android:entries="@array/location_update_interval"
        android:entryValues="@array/location_update_interval_values"
        android:dependency="track_option" />
</PreferenceCategory>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple: if you change the SharedPreference in `onSharedPreferenceChanged` you create a loop because you trigger yourself. The loop is actually a recursion and if you call yourself endlessly you fill up the memory (not the normal one - the "stack") until you get a stackoverflow.

a normal (somewhat useful) recursion looks like this:

```
public int sumAllNumbersUpTo (int number) {
    if (number > 0) {
        return number + sumAllNumbersUpTo(number - 1);
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int result = sumAllNumbersUpTo(3);
// result is 3 + ( 2 + ( 1 + ( 0 ) ) )
```

it is calling itself until some condition is met. If you remove that condition then this method will never end.

Comment: i dont get it. does that mean editor.commit() is causing the loop?

Comment: Exactly. `Editor.commit()` will call your `onSharedPreferenceChanged()` again once it has changed the preference.

Comment: thanks for the help!! just one more doubt. dont we need to commit the changes to checkboxpreference like we do in other cases? (i apologize if this sounds silly, but i was using preferences for the first time)

Comment: if your `onSharedPreferenceChanged()` is called then probably no because that means that something was just stored. But I don't know for sure - try it :)

Comment: If you set `android:key` on a `Preference`, it will be automatically saved for you when then user changes it. So you don't need to write any code.

Comment: thank u so much!!! i spend n entire day studying preferences but no one mentioned that!!